# Understanding dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am little confused regarding the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method and how it works. I currently have a searchBar and two mutable Arrays (say `filteredTableData` and `tableData`) . Now I just realized that no matter what I do `cell` always returns nil. I also  have a filter feature on my UITableView (using different arrays) however it seems to always return a nil. My question is when does `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` return something ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";   
MMTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MMTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.RowNo = indexPath.row;
        cell.ImageAlbum.image = [self getMP3Pic:indexPath.row];
        cell.table = self.tableViewObject;
    }



NSString* sng =  isFiltered ?  [self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

 cell.labelSongName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sng ];
 return cell;
```

}

Comment: Is the identifier set in your storyboard? Why are you not dequeuing the proper nib and instead grabbing it from a bundle?

Comment: I am using Interface Builder and the tableView is in a nib file

Comment: Did you set the row identifier in interface builder?

Comment: No I did not set it. I was reading an online tutorial and it did not mention that part

Comment: You need to set the cell identifier so that you can dequeue the cell properly. Then, cell will never be nil and you can configure the cell immediately.

Comment: Where do i set it in the interface builder ?

Comment: Click the cell, and in the right sidebar, go to the inspector tab. Then set the cell identifier to whatever you set in code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can register a nib for a reuse identifier in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere similar.

Comment: So in my nib I only have a UItableView and and I cant find the Table View Cell section in the interface builder. Maybe because I did not drag and drop a UITableViewCell in the interface builder. However One of my other nibs uses a custom UITableViewCell and I found the identifier in that. Why does my nib with only the UITableView not have that section.

Comment: Do you need to drag a UITableViewCell with UITableView onto the nib if you are not using a custom UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an optimization of displaying **UITableView**. Imagine that you have 1,000 of data to display and it does not make any sense to create 1,000 **UITableViewCell** in order to host each of your data. So, we use something called reusability that only a certain amount of cells will be used. When scrolling, it's not actually dealloc the invisible cells and create new cells. It's just move the existing cells around.

The identifiers are just used to identify different cells based on what you need. I might have multiple cell prototypes being used in one **UITableView**.

For your question, you will need to set up prototyped cells in the **Interface builder**. In the programmatical way, if we can not find the cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method, then we create. But, you can take advantage of **Interface Builder** and it will always return cell.

Comment: Do we have to always create a UITableViewCell from an interface builder ?

Comment: That's the better way. Otherwise, you will need to check whether reused cell is available.

Answer (score 2):

**dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** is nothing but reusing the Cell whenever applicable. Initially cell is always nil. So, we check for cell==nil condition and we will create UITableViewCell first time. When u scroll the tableview then dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will be called to reuse the cell which is already created at First Time.

You can modify your code as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";   
MMTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[MMTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] ;
 }
cell.RowNo = indexPath.row;
cell.ImageAlbum.image = [self getMP3Pic:indexPath.row];
cell.table = self.tableViewObject;

NSString* sng =  isFiltered ?  [self.filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

 cell.labelSongName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sng ];
 return cell;
}
```

Try it..Hope it helps you..!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I realized that I was missing resuseIdentifier